# web api 2 post with parameter - must use json.stringyfi

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-web-api, http-post, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using angularjs and I'm trying to make a HttpPost call to my web api.

My api method:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("authentication/getkey")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetKey([FromBody]string password) {
        //Do stuff
    }
```

my call:

```
service.getKey = function (password) {
            return $http.post('api/authentication/getkey', JSON.stringify(password))
                .then(function(result) {
                    return result.data;
                });
        }
```

Now this works fine, but do I really need to use `JSON.stringify`? I tried sending it like below, but all of them get password = null. Do I have to use `JSON.stringify` or am I doing it wrong in my other examples?

```
//Doesnt work
service.getKey = function (password) {
    return $http.post('api/authentication/getkey', password)
        .then(function(result) {
             return result.data;
         });
    }

//Doesnt work
service.getKey = function (password) {
    return $http.post('api/authentication/getkey', {password})
        .then(function(result) {
             return result.data;
         });
    }
```

Comment: You will need to send the data in your POST request as JSON format because by default angular $http service sends the Content-Type as application/json. The JSON.stringify will convert your data to to a JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) string. Is there a reason you don't want to use JSON.stringify? One way would be to change the Content-Type. I can provide some sample code if you want.

Comment: @VivekN please do that. I just wanna see other examples of how to do it - or how I should do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use JSON.stringify, the other option will be to send the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as pointed in other answer as well. This way you are sending the data as form data. I'm not sure about the syntax of the $http.post Shortcut method but the idea is the same.

```
service.getKey = function (password) {
    $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'api/authentication/getkey',
            data: $.param({ '': password }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        })
 .then(function(result) {
             return result.data;
         });
```

Answer (score 2):

From Microsoft's Web API official documentation about [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api):

> When a parameter has [FromBody], Web API uses the Content-Type header to select a formatter. In this example, the content type is "application/json" and the request body is a raw JSON string (not a JSON object).

Angular `$http` service sends `Content-Type: application/json` as header by default in POST requests, as you can see from the [official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers), so Web API is trying to bind your request body using his `JsonFormatter`. Because of this you have to provide him a well formatted Json string (not a Json Object with a string inside) to correctly bind his raw string parameter.

As a side note, you could also send a request using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as `Content-Type` header, but then you will have to format your body as form parameters (using something similar to jQuery `$.param( .. )`)